# Proving $(\alpha\beta)^n=\alpha^n\beta^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

This is potentially an obvious question I just need some clarification,
let $\alpha=(a_1,a_2,...,a_s)$ and $\beta=(b_1,b_2,...,b_r)$.  Prove for every positive integer $n$, $(\alpha\beta)^n = \alpha^n\beta^n$.

Can I begin with $(\alpha\beta)^n$ and distribute the $n$ to get $\alpha^n\beta^n$ or does that not prove this?

**EDIT:** Ok, I have revisited the question and discovered I had missed the part where it states that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint. Disjoint permutations are commutative. Therefore $$(\alpha\beta)^2=\alpha\beta\alpha\beta=\alpha\alpha\beta\beta=\alpha^2\beta^2.$$ Is this looking more correct?

Comment: Where do $\alpha$ and $\beta$ live?  What do you mean when you say that $\alpha = (a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_s)$?  Does $\alpha$ commute with $\beta$?  That is, do you have $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$?

Comment: I guess the product is componentwise, and $a_ib_i=b_ia_i, \forall i$. In this case you can start as you have mentioned. But you need to make sure $\alpha \beta =\beta \alpha$. By the way, here $r=s$ or not?

Comment: Your "proof" is the theorem itself, so no.

Comment: Once you have shown $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$, the proof is easy. And this equation must hold, otherwise the equation to be proven would be false for $n=2$. So, just prove that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ commute.

Comment: What is the product of two tuples of different sizes ???

Answer (score 1):

Invoking the definition of a power, an induction hypothesis, associativity of the product, commutativity of the product and a property of the powers,

$$(\alpha\beta)^n=(\alpha\beta)^{n-1}(\alpha\beta)=\alpha^{n-1}\beta^{n-1}\alpha\beta=\alpha\alpha^{n-1}\beta^{n-1}\beta=\alpha^n\beta^n.$$

Up to you to check availability of these properties.